# mapStateToProps is fired before the dispatch within componentDidMount, causing data to be undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, url-parameters, dispatch

I am trying to have the url parameters determine which 'article' is loaded.

However the mapStateToProps is firing first, and causing the article data to come up undefined. So an error message is thrown before the componentDidMount can fire (which is what is suppose to load the article data into the state). I have tried putting the dispatch in other places (like in render or in its own method), still the same issue.

This is my comonentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount(){
     const params = this.props.location.search.split('/');
     this.props.dispatch(getArticleStats({articleId:params[4]}));
```

This is my mapStateToProps:

```
    const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    return {
        user:    state.user,
        article: state.article
    }
}
```

The error I am getting shows the data in state.article is undefined, since dispatch has not fired yet:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'articleTitle' of undefined
```

Any wisdom or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make `mapStateToProps` fire after the `dispatch` call. `mapStateToProps` is a argument to `connect` which is a higher order component (HOC). This essentially makes your component a child in relation to the `connect` function.

The solution to your problem is most likely not to reorder the call of `dispatch`, but to handle the scenario where `article` is still undefined. A simple falsy check will most likely do the job: `if (this.props.article) ...`

Answer (score 0):

"Data is undefined when the component first mounts" is a pretty common issue in React.

Try adding a safeguard in your render method before attempting to render anything involving async data:

```
render() {
  return (
    {this.state.article &&
      <h1>{this.state.article.articleTitle}</h1>
      <div>{this.state.article.articleBody}</div>
    }
  )
}
```